# Existence of solution for all $t>0$ $y'(t)=Ay(t)+f(y)$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I saw theorems about the stability of the solution $y = 0$, but before we can talk about stability why does solution exist for all $t>0$?
$$y'(t)=Ay+f(y)$$
where  $f(y)$ is a Lipschitz function and
$$
f(y)||\leq||y||^{1+w}, \quad w>0.
$$

Comment: It's not true even when $A = 0$ in dimension one: for $y'= y^2$, there are solutions that are not defined for all $t >0$.

Comment: @ArcticChar, okay, if $\Re (\lambda_i)<0$ where $\lambda_i$ is eigenvalues of matrix $A$ we can use the Lyapunov theorem of existence solution for all $t>0$, becase we can find the Lyapunod function like $h(t) = <Hy(t),y(t)>$ where $H=H^*>0$ for $HA+A*H=-E$. But what if exist $\lambda_0, \Re(\lambda_0)>0$ Why does solution exist?

Comment: Positive eigenvalues does not help. Try $y' = y+ y^3$. I think you need some conditions on $\omega$.